# Sorting of y-axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a biographical dataset in two dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)
# dataframe of one-time ovents
one_timers <-
  tribble(~event, ~date,
          "birth", as.Date("1984/02/10"),
          "first toy", as.Date("1984/02/11"),
          "first kiss", as.Date("1992/05/15"),
          "moved out", as.Date("2003/08/29"),
          "first car", as.Date("2002/04/11"),
          "job", as.Date("2000/02/10"))
#dataframe of repeating events, say switchingt between companies that provide internet
sequence <-
  tribble(~event, ~from, ~to,  ~quality,
          "job", as.Date("2000/02/10"), as.Date("2000/02/17"), 2,
          "job", as.Date("2001/05/15"), as.Date("2001/06/10"), 4,
          "job", as.Date("2003/08/29"), as.Date("2004/02/10"), 5,
          "job", as.Date("2004/04/11"), as.Date("2005/01/10"), 10)
```

And I want create a plot of those events:

```
# plotting events
one_timers %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = event)) +
  geom_point()
```

Which results in:

[image: plot with wrong chronology]

This plot is okay, but I want events to be sorted chronologically, so I'm switching my `event` variable to factor end reorder it according to date:

```
one_timers <-
  one_timers %>% 
  mutate(event = event %>% as.factor() %>% forcats::fct_reorder(date))
levels(one_timers$event)
# and it works
one_timers %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = event)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot with fixed chronology]

But now let's complicate it with additional layer, that uses different dataframe. This layer will be *under* the points (it works just OK if it's above):

```
one_timers %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = event)) +
  geom_segment(data = sequence,
               aes(x = from,
                   xend = to,
                   y = event,
                   yend = event,
                   colour = quality),
               size = 3) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot with broken chronology again]

I've tried coercing `event` from second dataframe to factor with the same levels and ordering, but it's not that (picture doesn't change at all):

```
factors <- list(one_timers$event, sequence$event %>% as.factor())
sequence$event <- fct_unify(fs = factors)[[2]]  
sequence$event

one_timers %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = event)) +
  geom_segment(data = sequence,
               aes(x = from,
                   xend = to,
                   y = event,
                   yend = event,
                   colour = quality),
               size = 3) +
  geom_point()
# still doesn't work
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, that adding the segment layer confuses the axis.
I managed to work around by introducing a numerical variable:

```
one_timers <- one_timers %>% mutate(eventNum = as.numeric(event))
sequence <- sequence %>% mutate(eventNum = which(levels(one_timers$event) %in% event))

one_timers %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = eventNum)) +
  geom_segment(data = sequence,
               aes(x = from,
                   xend = to,
                   y = eventNum,
                   yend = eventNum,
                   colour = quality),
               size = 3) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous("event", 
                   breaks = one_timers$eventNum, 
                   labels = as.character(one_timers$event))
```

[image]